# How to connect to a cluster local RabbitMQ Kubernetes service from an Istio application

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, istio

We have an application with a dependency on RabbitMQ which is deployed inside the kubernetes cluster as a standard statefulset / service style deployment (using helm stable/rabbitmq-ha). We then in a separate namespace have an application deployed in a similar style deployment / service layout but with istio enabled (including sidecar injection).

As soon as we turn on istio sidecar injection the deployment can no longer connect to the kubernetes service.

I've tried putting in an istio ServiceEntry in with the FQDN of each RabbitMQ pod but that seemingly hasn't made a difference.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  hosts:
    - "rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-0.rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-discovery.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local"
    - "rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-1.rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-discovery.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local"
    - "rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-2.rabbitmq-rabbitmq-ha-discovery.rabbitmq.svc.cluster.local"
  ports:
    - number: 4369
      name: epmd
      protocol: TCP
    - number: 5672
      name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
    - number: 15672
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    - number: 25672
      name: inter-node
      protocol: TCP
...
```

I can see traffic makes it to the RabbitMQ pod but with Istio turned on it throws the following error:

```
2019-06-19 09:40:39.538 [info] <0.32110.48> accepting AMQP connection <0.32110.48> (10.233.122.234:47530 -> 10.233.122.85:5672)
2019-06-19 09:40:39.538 [error] <0.32110.48> closing AMQP connection <0.32110.48> (10.233.122.234:47530 -> 10.233.122.85:5672):
{bad_header,<<22,3,1,0,222,1,0,0>>}
```

The only thought I do have at the moment is that RabbitMQ does resolve the Kubernetes DNS into each specific pod using a plugin (rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s), could that be interferring?

Just to be clear I have no interest in enabling Istio mTLS in between the application and RabbitMQ just to have fully functional basic connectivity.

We're using:

- Kubernetes 1.3.0
- Istio 1.1.9
- RabbitMQ 3.7.12

Comment: How about remove `EntryPoint`? I think it is no need.

Comment: @menya Do you mean the ServiceEntry? It doesn't work with or without and doesn't appear to make any difference at all when I add / remove it.

Comment: What is your RMQ client, RMQ cluster works well in my situation.

Comment: @menya We're using https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit which uses the official client underneath. I'm happy to spin up a quick container using whichever client you are to help debug.

Comment: RMQ clueter is transparent for client, so connect to any node is OK. How do you connect to your RMQ? Are your RMQ behind a `service`?

Comment: @menya I'm connecting to a kubernetes service DNS entry; this works without Istio enabled.

Comment: Have you checked `global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode` parameter whether mode `ALLOW_ANY` has been enabled as described [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#envoy-passthrough-to-external-services)?